# How can I convert facebook event start_time to local time ?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to show when event occurs in local time. 
1. What is time zone of start_time in [event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/) table ? 
2. How convert this time to local time. For example gmt+2

FQL:
fql?q={"eventmembers": 'select eid from event_member where uid = me()', 'events': 'select eid, name, tagline, pic_big, host, event_type, event_subtype, start_time, creator, location, venue from event where eid in (select eid from #eventmembers) and start_time > 1332337956'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in Facebook is converted to Pacific time. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

You can pass in your own time zone to an event when you create it.

Comment: so do I need to subtract 8h from start_time (PST) to get UTC ?

Comment: Not necessarily, because you need to take DST into account as well. Your language of choice most likely has a convertToUTC-type function. I would use that.